# Server Side Language for beginners

Tags: server-side

I have just learnt client side scripting and now I wanted to start learning server side scripting.I am confused whether I should learn python,PHP or Ruby on Rails or any other language.Please recommend a language that would suit perfect to a beginner and some resources from where I can learn.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby on Rails is super easy to learn. PHP is faster to execute and can scale better, but is known to be a little bloated (search PHP hammer) as for Python.... Never had any use for it. If it is your first server scripting language go for Ruby on Rails (search for [Twitter for Zombies](http://railsforzombies.org/))

Comment: I heard ruby on rails has scalability issues which is why twitter has stopped using it.......Is it good enough for long run??

Comment: You could learn it in a weekend and is decent to use for mobile development. If you want something long term PHP leads the market right now.

Answer (score 0):

If by client side scripting you mean JavaScript in the browser, your natural and easiest choice to start with will be Node.js for the server side.